# ASP.Net Core MVC Disable validation when a specific button is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-3.1

I have 2 buttons on my form, a Submit and Save button. I want to be able to skip all validation when a user clicks the Save button. I've tried adding `class="cancel"`, `formnovalidate`, `formnovalidate="formnovalidate"`, `disableValidation="true"` to the Save button but none of them worked. Any help would be wonderful! I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1.

**Form**

```
<form asp-action="Request">
...
...
<input name="answer" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input name="answer" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-secondary" />
</form>
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
```

Comment: `formnovalidate` attribute only has to do with HTML5 validation, nothing to do with this plugin.   Try `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` if you want a button that does not trigger validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,you need to know,if you use `_ValidationScriptsPartial`,it would generate the html like below:

Generate cshtml from:

```
<input asp-for="MyDate" class="form-control" />
```

to:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" data-val="true"
    data-val-required="The MyDate field is required."
    id="MyDate" name="MyDate" value="">
```

`formnovalidate` and `class="cancel"` attribute could skip the validation in client side,but could not skip validation in server side.

To fix such issue,you could clear model state:

1.Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2.View(add `formnovalidate` to `save input`):

```
@model Test
<form asp-action="Request">
    <div>
        Name:<input asp-for="Name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        Id:<input asp-for="Id" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <input name="answer" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <input name="answer" type="submit" value="Save" formnovalidate class="btn btn-secondary" />
</form>
@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

3.Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Request(Test test)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         ModelState.Clear();
         return View("Index");
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: This solved the problem! I also had an internal RCL that was running validation that I didn't realize. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form asp-action="Request">
...
...
<input name="answer" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
<input name="answer" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-secondary cancel" />
</form>

@section Scripts{
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```