# FormNoValidate when using a custom ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validationattribute

**UPDATE**

I have gotten around my issue by limiting the `ModelState.IsValid` check to not test when the button pressed was the delete. So maybe this IS the real fix, but if there were something I could test in the validation context to determine if I should or should not run the validation logic, that would be a slicker solution.

---

I have created a custom validation attribute and it works great (well except for this issue). I have multiple submit buttons on my form. One of those buttons has the `formnovalidate` attribute set.

However my custom validation is still being fired off and preventing the UI from processing. I'm guessing that in my custom validation class, there is something I may need to check to see if the button pressed that triggered the validation had that attribute set?

For simplicity - this is my model class:

```
[CustomValidation(ErrorMessage = "Please Select a choice")]
public List<SelectListItem> Foo { get; set; }
```

View

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" name="command" value="Delete" title="Delete">
Delete
</button>
```

Custom validation

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // Dummy Holder for testing.. not the real logic
        if (value != null)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60440119/asp-net-core-mvc-disable-validation-when-a-specific-button-is-pressed#comment106930029_60440119).

Answer (score 0):

-> First you can check FormNoValidate attribute is available or not in the request and attributes of the submit button that triggered validation.

-> In this modification code, the FormNoValidate attribute is not present that time we skip the validation logic.

-> Code :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

public class CustomValidation : ValidationAttribute
{
  protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, 
  ValidationContext validationContext)
  {
       // Check if the request contains the formnovalidate attribute
       var httpContext = 
       validationContext.GetService(typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)) as 
       HttpContextAccessor;
       var formNoValidate = 
       httpContext?.HttpContext?.Request?.Form["formnovalidate"];

       // If formnovalidate is present, skip validation
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formNoValidate))
       {
          return ValidationResult.Success;
       }

        // Dummy Holder for testing.. not the real logic
        if (value != null)
        {
           return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        }
      }
    }
```